# Como criar um index único em uma tabela para que ela só tenha um registro com um valor específico no SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server

Olá, estou criando uma estrutura de dados no SQLServer e tenho a seguinte situação:

- Tenho uma lista de tipos de contatos (pessoa, publico, comercial, etc...)
- Essa lista pode ser alterada pelo usuário mas, obrigatoriamente ela só pode ter 1 elemento como default.

A estrutura da tabela fica assim:

```sql
create table TipoContato (
    id int not null identity(1,1),
    descricao nvarchar(100) not null,
    padrao bit not null constraint [DF_TipoContato.padrao] default 0
);
create unique index [UX_TipoContato.descricao] 
    on TipoContato(descricao);
```

Existe alguma forma que, eu possa forçar o SQL a aceitar somente um registro como 1 para a coluna padrão? A intenção é que, caso seja passado em um `INSERT` ou `UPDATE` o padrão como 1, deve-se forçar todos os elementos a serem 0 além do informado.

Obs: tenho ciência que posso fazer isso via `TRIGGER`, mas não vejo como sendo a melhor forma possível de fazê-lo... há uma forma mais inteligente de resolver o caso?

Comment: Qual o problema do uso do _TRIGGER_?

Comment: o problema é que além de não ficar diretamente acoplado à tabela e sim a uma estrutura procedural externa, dificulta a manutenibilidade do código de geração das tabelas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a versão do SQL Server for superior à 2008, você pode criar um [índice filtrado](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-2017):

```
create table TipoContato (
    id int not null identity(1,1),
    descricao nvarchar(100) not null,
    padrao bit not null constraint [DF_TipoContato.padrao] default 0
);
create unique index [UX_TipoContato.descricao]  on TipoContato(descricao);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_padrao_unico ON TipoContato (padrao) WHERE padrao = 1;
```

Se você tentar fazer isso:

```
insert into TipoContato  (descricao,padrao) values ('Test 1',0);
insert into TipoContato  (descricao,padrao) values ('Test 2',1);--padrao true
insert into TipoContato  (descricao,padrao) values ('Test 3',0);
insert into TipoContato  (descricao,padrao) values ('Test 4',0);
insert into TipoContato  (descricao,padrao) values ('Test 5',0);
insert into TipoContato  (descricao,padrao) values ('Test 6',0);
insert into TipoContato  (descricao,padrao) values ('Test 7',1);--erro
```

a segunda tentativa de se inserir um valor true para a coluna padrão vai ocasionar um erro:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.TipoContato' with
>   unique index 'IX_padrao_unico'. The duplicate key value is (1).

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1910c/6).

A idéia é capturar a excessão e agir de alguma maneira. A coluna padrao foi setada por erro ou foi intencional?

Agora se você quiser que sempre quando a coluna padrão for setada à **true** a anterior seja alterada para **false**, não tem como fugir de uma **trigger**.

Comment: era isso mesmo que eu tava querendo saber... infelizmente eu sei que não tem como fugir de uma trigger em casos como esse, mas o que posso fazer é fazer um update antes limpando essas referencias... meu sistema será escalável então não é só 1 usuário que acessará o bd...

Comment: além disso, pelo q vi na documentação, posso criar multiplicidade de relações entre tabelas para uma mesma coluna rs